# What user does SSMS database creation run under?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a (S:\) drive with permissions for only myself and the `SYSTEM` user.

I just downloaded SQL SERVER EXPRESS 2017, and when I go to create a new database, it cannot see that drive as a place to create the database.

I tried giving the `Everyone` group full permissions on the drive, and then it showed up as a place to make the new database.

I am wondering what user I need to actually give permissions too, as it is clearly not running under my user, since my user has full control on the drive, and it's not running as `SYSTEM`, since that user has full control of the drive. I don't want to give "Everyone" permissions to the drive.

Note: Doing a bit more experiments, after removing the `Everyone` permissions, I went looking through my users list (in the Security tab of the Drive properties), and the only user that looks to have anything to do with SQL is `SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser${myUserName}`, but giving this user full control did not allow SSMS to see the drive again.

Comment: What user account did you specify when installing SQL Server as the account the service should run under?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I just used the default account name, which I believe is `NT Service\MSSQL$MSSQLSERVER` (Which isn't in my users list on the permissions tab)

Comment: Then that's the account that needs permission. Or you could create a service account, give it the needed permissions on the require files and then give it permission to `S:\ `.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_server_services
```

And you will see current available services on your SQL Server instance and the account mapped to each one. Add permissions to the one that's below the `servicename: SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)`, it will be most likely `NT Service\MSSQLSERVER`.

If you use Jobs on the Agent, you will need to give permissions to that account also.

Comment: That gave me the user, then https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-file-system-permissions-for-database-engine-access?view=sql-server-2017 explained how to give it permissions. It wasn't in the list, but I was able to manually type it in and it worked